# How to install java 1.8 in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I hava a mac and It has java JVM 1.6 that I use in eclipse kepler and I want to update the JVM to 1.8. How do I do that?

Comment: Well, you install Java 1.8 and then configure eclipse to use it. Note that eclipse will not gain support for any of the features in Java 8 by doing so, for that you'd need to upgrade to Luna or Mars.

Comment: Window->Preferences->Java->Installed JREs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply install it (e.g. https://askubuntu.com/questions/464755/how-to-install-openjdk-8-on-14-04-lts)

Then add it to the JDK selection in Preferences/Java/Installed JREs:

[image]

You may have to search for the JDK path (e.g. in /usr/lib/java or /Libraries/java)

Answer (score 0):

Install the JDK on your OS.

Then, check the preferences and look for Java->Installed JREs.  Click add.  (On Windows, it is Windows->Preferences, or Eclipse->Preferences on a Mac).